How does React props work with es6 and object inheritance between classes
I don't even know if this is possible, something told me to do functional components but I am already too far deep into the code and I am scared to go back (this is an issue I must learn to tackle but I need confirmation possibly that it should be done this way).
I am in a coding bootcamps and we have two days to learn React. I am currently doing a project and these are my files. Some pseudocode is here to help me understand things, I am also using Babel to compile as I go.
The problem is I am trying to get videos to show up on my site. exampleVideoData is an array of objects that have fake video data. We are trying to make a site similar to YouTube, which means later on this example video data will be referenced via APIs. However I am not understanding how to use the keyword "props". It seems to work when I put in a string, but when I try to reference the exampleVideoData in the property "videos" of my App object as the value it does not work. The class VideoList should be inheriting the information from App.
I'm thinking my this keyword is pointing to the wrong thing or maybe props is being misused. But I the more I toyed around with it the more janked up things became. So I ctrl-z'd back to this point when things still rendered to the page. I want my VideoPlayer element to have the exampleVideoData2. Here are the files and how they look:
App.js
import VideoPlayer from "/compiled/src/components/VideoPlayer.js";
import exampleVideoData2 from "../data/exampleVideoData2.js";
import VideoList from "/compiled/src/components/VideoList.js";
import Search from "/compiled/src/components/Search.js"

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super()
    this.videos = exampleVideoData2
  }
  
  render() { 
    return(
  <div>
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div><h5><em>search</em> view goes here</h5></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-7">
        <div><h5><VideoPlayer /></h5></div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-5">
        <div><h5><VideoList videos= { this.props.videos }/></h5></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)};
}
//whatever happens here, happens there
// In the ES6 spec, files are "modules" and do not share a top-level scope
// `var` declarations will only exist globally where explicitly defined

export default App;

VideoList.js
import exampleVideoData2 from "/compiled/src/data/exampleVideoData.js";
import VideoListEntry from "/compiled/src/components/VideoListEntry.js"

class VideoList extends React.Component{ 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.videos = exampleVideoData2
  }  
  videos(){
    return(exampleVideoData2)
  }
  render(){ return (
  <div className="video-list">
    <div><h5> videos: {  this.props.videos }</h5></div>
    <div><h5><em>videoListEntry</em> view goes here</h5></div>
    <div><h5><em>videoListEntry</em> view goes here</h5></div>
    <div><h5><em>videoListEntry</em> view goes here</h5></div>
    <div><h5><em>videoListEntry</em> view goes here</h5></div>
  </div>
)};
};
// PropTypes tell other developers what `props` a component expects
// Warnings will be shown in the console when the defined rules are violated
VideoList.propTypes = {
  videos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

// In the ES6 spec, files are "modules" and do not share a top-level scope.
// `var` declarations will only exist globally where explicitly defined.
export default VideoList;

Summary: How do I get "props" or my VideoList to reference the exampleVideoData using object inheritance? Should I refactor everything to functional components? -cheers

Don't assign this.videos = exampleVideoData2 but then try to access this.props.videos. The same problem in both your components.

I FIGURED IT OUT YALL:
in my index.jsx file, I had to change the way everything was being rendered:
// TODO: Render the `App` component to the DOM
import searchYouTube from './lib/searchYouTube.js';
import YOUTUBE_API_KEY from './config/youtube.js';
import App from './components/App.js';
import exampleVideoData2 from './data/exampleVideoData2.js';

ReactDOM.render(<App videos={exampleVideoData2}/>, document.getElementById('app'))

before this, I did NOT have videos tacked onto App being set to a value. Now I just need to figure out how to loop through these values. Going to go about it using map because I don't think regular for loops can be used on React. Also:
I know render is deprecated and I should be using createRoot & root but I did not have any more time to waste figuring out the terminal commands needed in order to do so and plus I noticed they do not have the react.client file anywhere in this repo. Cheers

You add a videos property to App component,but it isn't a wise way to solve your problem. If you do this, then your App component may extend more properties as your project expands. You'd better think how to solve problem in a better way no just solve it by anyway, it means you didn't master it, just cover it.
Your fake data may comes from API or other source, so you could set state in your App component.
// set exampleVideoData2 as initial value
this.state = {
  videos: exampleVideoData2
};

// in element
<div><h5><VideoList videos= { this.state.videos }/></h5></div>

And you can extend it by get it in some lifecircle (depends on your function).
